# RightJS Lightbox Plugin Not Working In IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, lightbox, rightjs

I am using the RightJS Lightbox plugin for a Lightbox to show inline HTML data. It works perfectly in FF and Chrome but alas IE is a no-go. I had it working yesterday for a short time and have tried to retrace my steps to no avail.

Here is a link the the applicable code: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarcello/QuwfE/. The full version can also be viewed here: http://www.buenolisto.com/alma

A simple elegant fix would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone has another lightweight solution that provides a light box supporting inline HTML that would be great.

By lightweight I guess I mean with minimal files and preferably without having to connect in to yet another style sheet which is why I like the RightJS solution.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/YHwyr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/YHwyr/, you seems like have broken links, it didn't download right.js from your site